# Run a single unit test with igloo

Tags: c++, unit-testing, igloo

I'm working on a Codewars Kata and I ran into an issue. All Katas are implemented as unit tests based on igloo using `Describe` and `It`. I use the following code to run all unit tests:

```cpp
#include <igloo/igloo_alt.h>
#include <igloo/CodewarsTestListener.h>
using namespace igloo;
using namespace snowhouse;

int main(int, const char* []) {
    const ColoredConsoleTestResultsOutput output;
    TestRunner runner(output);
    CodewarsTestListener listener;
    runner.AddListener(&listener);
    runner.Run();
}
```

For debugging the problem I currently have, I'd like to run a single test only.

My gut feeling is that I need a `ContextRunner` and a `Context`, but [the search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=igloo+context+contextrunner) are miserable.

How do I run a single test (a single `Describe`) with Igloo?